# Adding Azure Virtual machine to an existing availability set

Tags: azure

I want to create two virtual machines in Azure which should not be connected to each other. I created first virtual machine and also created an availability set as part of its creation process.

Now when I create the second virtual machine then I don't get the availability set created as part of first virtual machine in the drop down list of availability sets.

However if I try to connect the second virtual machine as part of first one then I am able to see the availability set created as part of first virtual machine.

Is it mandatory for virtual machines to be connected to each other so that I can add them to the same availability set? Is this a limitation only from azure portal and there is a workaround using powershell?

UPDATE:

If we connect two virtual machines then we can get the benefit of availability set. However, at the same time both virtual machine becomes part of same cloud service and hence are load balanced by azure which does not support sticky session.

My scenerio is that I have identical front-ends which needs to support sticky session. Therefore I don't want to connect them to each other. However, I want to get the benefits of availability sets as mentioned in the article on [Availability sets](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/manage-vm-availability/).

So can I set availability set for two identical virtual machines not connected to each other?

Comment: When you consider "availability set" it means you want to bring two machines under one service name and they must be connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "Availability Set" means that you want to bring one or more VM within one service group for maximize the availability during an event of downtime. So what you see on Azure Portal is correct behavior however you might have some misunderstanding with regard to Availability Set. You can read more on "Availability Set" [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/manage-vm-availability/).

So when you try to connect second virtual machine as part of first, you do see the availability set, because this way you want your VM to use the settings from the first and add another VM to the same group to maximize the availability. This second VM becomes the part of first one.

When you create an independent VM (call is second or 3rd or any) you are actually creating a brand new VM which is going to run independent to any other VM you may or may not have and thats why you dont see "availability set" instead you can create a new "availability set" based on this new VM.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have updated the question with more details. So what I understand is that to add two VMs to same availability set they should be connected to each other.

Comment: I have one Vm, and i want to clone the main VM to make a copy and connect to the AvailabilitySet, but does this means i have to manage 2 different VHD disks, and OS, and updates, and everything in double?

Comment: That's a great question, @Miguel. Did you ever find out if that is indeed a consequence of the availability sets? Or the somehow automatically redundant?

Comment: Im not sure. But im thinking about a test, that is, mount a virtual partition that its source is a azure blob storage. So that way i can have one single blob with all the database data folder, shared among many virtual machines...

Answer (score 0):

## Set AvailabilitySet using Powershell

```
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName "savilltech101" -Name "WebSrv3" | Set-AzureAvailabilitySet -AvailabilitySetName "IIS" | Update-AzureVM
```