# Set Virtual Machine Availability Set

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

When creating a VM in Azure, you have the option of setting an Availability Set and Fault/Update domain. I have some VMs where I need to set the Availability Set and another set of VMs where I need to update the Fault/Update domain.

As far as I can see, this isn't available with the new Resource Group-based Virtual Machines and cmdlets, thus [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337916/adding-azure-virtual-machine-to-an-existing-availability-set) isn't applicable. Without recreating the VMs, what is the proper way to set these resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because availability set membership determines which stamp (cluster) a VM will be created in, it isn't possible to configure the availability set after the machine is deployed.

The simplest solution would be to delete the VM, while retaining the disks, then create your availability set and create and add new VMs with the existing disks.

Comment: I wanted to mention that I am using CLI to create VM and add to existing availability set. The logs indicate the command option was read and the set was found but the VM was never added to the set. The only way I have gotten this to work so far is creating the VM using ARM.